# Visual SVN Server: User Management mixed-mode possible?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have a question concerning the User Management:

Is there a way (maybe in the Enterprise Version) to run Visual SVN Server in "mixed mode" (AD+local Usermanagement)?

I mean there is a configuration to run Visual SVN with local Usermanagemen (without Active Directory)

OR

Windows-based User Management (Active Directory Connection.

I there a way to mix this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, one VisualSVN Server installation can use either Windows/AD -based authentication or use local standalone Subversion accounts. With Windows authentication you can also use local Windows accounts, though. See the following articles:

- https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00039/
- https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/

Note that you can deploy secondary server and set up the [Multisite Repository Replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) feature. Enable local Subversion authentication on that secondary server and the users of the first server will use Windows authentication, the users of secondary server will use local standalone Subversion accounts. That's very helpful if you need to deploy a server in DMZ.